# tabulator upload JSON to the server

Tags: javascript, tabulator

i'm using Tabulator to Mange some tables and i've see how to download the file in JSON format and others but i wonder if there's a function included to save data in JSON object instead so I can upload it directly to the server

i've checked this page http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/download and i got the idea to use "Custom File Formatter" then intercept the download bolb  but i keep getting an error referring to

`setFileContents(names.join(", "), "text/plain");`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setFileContents is not defined
```

function code:

```
document.querySelector("#uploadJSON").onclick = function(){
var fileFormatter = function(columns, data, options){
var names = [];
data.forEach(function(row){
    names.push(row.name);
});

setFileContents(names.join(", "), "text/plain");
}
table.download(fileFormatter, "test.json");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***getData*** function to get an array of row data objects:

```
var data = table.getData();
```

And then JSON encode it with the stringify function:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

It is then down to you to choose how to upload it to the server, in-fact several ajax libraries will even do the JSON encoding for you so you would just need to pass them the results from the ***getData*** function